# Why use Stripe webhooks instead of subscription.status?

Tags: stripe-payments, webapi

I am working on integrating stripe subscriptions in a website. So, I am thinking about using the `subscription.status` to monitor payment. So, once the current period ends, I check the subscription. If active, great, I update the user data. If not, then I act accordingly based on the status.

However, it seems to be that webhooks are the correct way to do this. Why is that better than just checking the status? It seems pretty much the same to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using webhooks will allow you to keep a track of a whole bunch of things rather than just the status of a subscription [1].

You can design a webhook endpoint to listen to various events such as;

- Whenever a new subscription is created or an existing subscription is
  canceled
- In case you offer multiple plans for subscription, you will
  be notified if a customer switches from one plan to another
- Whenever an invoice is created, finalized, paid or in-case payment attempt fails

If you don't use webhooks, you will have to constantly poll for status changes until the status actually does change. That approach isn’t really scalable. So instead of having to keep looking for the information, with a webhook the information would come to you.

So instead of having to keep looking for the information, information itself would come to you. You can use the webhook events as triggers to handle any operations you’d want to perform on your backend.

It will also increase the scalability of your app as there are plenty of other events you can listen for [2].

[1] https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks#use-cases

[2] https://stripe.com/docs/api/webhook_endpoints/create#create_webhook_endpoint-enabled_events